# Rails - Problem in Creating Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

I'm using a model that belongs to 2 other models. When I try to create it, I manage to get both ids, but the content itself isn't stored in database

```
 def create
    @person = Person.find(current_person)
    @message = Message.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), :person => Person.find(current_person))
    if @message.save
      redirect_to(:back)
    else
      redirect_to(:back)
    end
  end



<% form_for(:message, :url => messages_path(:person_id => current_person.id, :group_id => @group.id)) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content %> 
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<%end %>
```

Also, `content` is set as text in database and I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: When you call `create` method on the model it trues to save it into the database.  Probably, you need to call `new` to initialize new instance.  Or, if you like `create` method - use `new_record?` to see if it is saved some instance or not (due to failed validation or something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@message = Message.create params[:message].merge(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), :person => Person.find(current_person))
```

Answer (score 1):

@why's answer above should do it for you. But you can go a step above and use the power of associations.

In your message.rb, you would have the association

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :person
  ...
end
```

You could also have a similar association in Group / Person models which declares a has_many relationship.

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :messages
   ...
 end

 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :messages
   ...
 end
```

In **routes.rb** (Rails 2.3.x)

```
 map.resources :group, :has_many => [:messages]
```

In **routes.rb** (Rails 3)

```
 resources :groups do
   resources :messages
 end
```

This will give you a route like

```
POST group_messages_path(:group_id) # => this will route to 
                                    # MessagesController's create action
                                    # and provide params[:group_id]
```

You are using current_person which seems to be current login related, so it would not be a good idea to make it visible or editable thru the url or parameters. current_person should be derived from the session in the create action itself.

```
# form_for([@group,:message]) or form_for([@group,@message])
# automatically works out the path as POST /groups/:group_id/messages => MessagesController#create
# And current person association remains safe to currently logged in person
# without being revealed thru parameters and such.

<% form_for([@group,@message]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %> 
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>


def create
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @person = current_person # or however you find current_person
  @message = @group.messages.build(params[:messaage])
  @message.person = @person
  if @message.save
    redirect_to(:back)
  else
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 @message = Message.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), :person => Person.find(current_person))
```

to
     `@message = Message.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), :person => Person.find(current_person), :content => params[:content]`)